# NixOS: recover /boot mount info after overwriting hardware-configuration.nix

Tags: nixos

In my NixOS configuration I ended up accidentally overwriting my `hardware-configuration.nix`. While `sudo nixos-generate-config` regenerates one, for me the regenerated version appears to be missing the required `/boot` section.

How can I figure out what this section was / should have been like?

I checked e.g. `/nix/var/nix/profiles/`, but couldn't find it in there.
`lsblk` shows me some partitions including a `sr0` that seems like what should be my `/boot`:

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 923.5G  0 part /tmp/c7ca628b-0645-4af0-95d5-741d47d5923f
└─sda2   8:2    0     8G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0 119.2G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 119.2G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

... however, trying to plug this in did not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC `nixos-generate-config` generates mounts simply based on what is *currently* mounted.  So... one option is to mount stuff by hand the way you want it and then run the generator.  I guess if you have previous system generations that work the way you want, you can boot into one of them via the grub menu and run `nixos-generate-config` from them.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this, but the `/boot` isn't in the generated file, giving me a bit of a chicken-and-egg problem: getting it into a generated config implies having it mounted, while mounting it implies knowing what to mount (and how). e.g. trying `sudo mount /dev/sr0 /tmp/sr0` gives me `mount: /tmp/sr0: no medium found on /dev/sr0.`

Comment: I assumed that you *do* have an older system generation in grub that does know how to mount it.

Comment: I imagine it 'knew' in the sense it managed to boot... but I ended up just formatting instead now. Thanks for your help!